# Controller checkEmail returns "Error parsing JSON: undefined false" for 'false', 'true' works as intended

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I've got a little problem with returning false from controller. First off, true is being returned normally as "true" in JSON without any problem, but when it should return false this is displayed :

```
Error parsing JSON: undefined
undefined:

false
```

Here is my DAO

```
@Override
    public Boolean checkEmail(String email) {
        System.out.println(email);
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM StudenciEntity s WHERE s.email LIKE :email");
        query.setParameter("email", email);
        if (query.getResultList().isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Here is Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/email/{email:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> checkEmail(@PathVariable String email) {
        Boolean checkEmail = istudenciService.checkEmail(email);
        if (checkEmail !=null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(checkEmail, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
            return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

At the beginning i was returning Long for email (1 and -1) and it worked, then wanted to make it boolean and all this happened.

Comment: Server side looks OK to me,how are you parsing json at front end?

Comment: I'm using Postman plugin for Chrome to test REST.

Comment: I'm receiving the same error.  It seems to be a POSTMan bug.  I've logged an issue here: https://github.com/a85/POSTMan-Chrome-Extension/issues/1053